# Stopping a sensorListenser

Tags: android, listener

I add a sensorListener(code from  to my app, the allow the user shake the phone in order to start the game.

How do I disable the sensor after the first shake?

I got the sensor code  from [here](http://www.anddev.org/clockapps_-_countdown_timer_and_stopwatch-t3730.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API indicates that there is an "unregister method":
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#unregisterListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor%29

After you have received your event you can use the Sensor Manager to unregister it - but your current code may use deprecated methods. You may want to have a look at this API to make sure it is up to date.